# Why variance is not squared before scaling for rolling dice problem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, dice, variance, means

I am trying to calculate mean $E[Y]$ and variance $Var[Y]$ of sums, when rolling a dice of 6 outcomes $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$, 10 times. I get the mean as below.

**Mean of sums for 10 tosses**

$
Y = 10X, \\ \\
E[Y] = E[10X] = 10E[X] \\ \\
E[X] = 1 \frac{1}{6} + 2 \frac{1}{6} + 3 \frac{1}{6} + 4 \frac{1}{6} + 5 \frac{1}{6} + 6 \frac{1}{6} 
= \frac{21}{6} = 3.5 \\ \\
E[Y] = 10E[X] = 10(3.5) = 35 \\ \\
$

**Variance for 10 tosses**

Here I thought as follows.
$
Var[Y] = Var[10X] = 10^2Var[X] = 100Var[X] \\
Var[X] = \frac{(1-3.5)^2}{6} + \frac{(2-3.5)^2}{6} + \frac{(3-3.5)^2}{6} + \frac{(4-3.5)^2}{6} + \frac{(5-3.5)^2}{6} + \frac{(6-3.5)^2}{6} \\
= 2.91  \\
Var[Y] = 100(2.91) = 291
$

However as per [here](http://sugarpillstudios.com/wp/?page_id=1004), Variance is

$
Var[Y] = 10Var[X] = 10(2.91) = 29.1
$

because each throw is an independent event.  I also verified statistically this being correct.

**Questions:**
1. If each throw is an independent event, then mean would have been $E[X_1 + X_2 + \cdot + X_10]$, Isn't it? I could not imagine how $E[X_1] = \frac {10}{6}$ and so on?
2. I am confused when to apply scaling $E[aX]$ or $E[X_1 + X_2 + \cdot + X_10]$. Because, this affects variance as above, while both assumption for mean might result in same value.  Kindly clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is right at the beginning: it's actually not true that $Y = 10X$. That would be equivalent to rolling one die and multiplying the result by $10$, which is quite a different process than rolling ten dice and taking their sum. (*Proof*: The probability that [the sum of ten dice is $10$] is $6^{-10}$, but the probability that [a single die rolled multiplied by $10$ is $10$] is $1/6$.)

What you really want here is $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i$, where the $X_i$ represent independent die rolls. From here, it follows that 
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \operatorname{Var} \left( \sum_{i=1}^{10} X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} \operatorname{Var}(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} 2.91 = 29.1.$$

EDIT: Oops, I forgot to answer your questions at the end as well!

1. Means are additive, yes.
2. Apply scaling only when you are genuinely multiplying a random variable by something, which is distinct from taking a sum. An example of a genuine scaling problem is, for instance, if you were to take the result of a die roll and double it (as opposed to rolling two dice and adding their results).

Comment: Great but Mean would be same for both $Y=10X$ and $Y = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}X_i$ ? So both scaling and independent rolls have same mean, still probability variations different?

Comment: Yes, it's true that means do scale and add in the obvious way -- but the scaling and adding have differing effects on variances. Put another way: $\mathbb E[10 X] = 10 \mathbb E[X]$, and $\mathbb E[\sum X_i] = \sum \mathbb E[X_i]$.

Comment: I did not understand " The probability that [the sum of ten dice is 10] is $6^{−10}$, but the probability that [a single die rolled multiplied by 10 is 10] is $\frac{1}{6}$.)". Can you kindly elaborate on that.

Comment: First, roll ten dice and add their values. You'll get a sum of $10$ if and only if all ten dice came up $1$, and since each die is independent, the probability of this is $\frac 1 6 \cdot \frac 1 6 \cdots \frac 1 6 = 6^{-10}$. On the other hand, roll one die and multiply its result by 10. That value will be 10 if and only if the die originally came up a 1, which will occur $\frac 1 6$ of the time.

Comment: And do we have any derived formula like we have $np$ and $npq$ as mean and variance for many coin flips?

Comment: If $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ denote the mean and variance of any random variable, then the mean and variance of a sum of $n$ independent copies of them are, respectively, $n \mu$ and $n \sigma^2$. Any formulas would be a consequence of that idea (as is the coin flip formula you cited).

Comment: Can you also please check my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869773/what-is-what-between-binomial-many-flip-outcomes-and-statistical-observation)